# How to rollup multiple lines into a single line starting with a specific text

Tags: text-processing

How can I roll up multiple lines into a single line starting with a specific text?

For example:

```
P220002009034028180002          SSM      200903
P22200I2004220000     0408832000000000 
P222500903200000015{ 
P22261000005500000 
P22200I2008660000    8532818700000000 
P22467809000033336{ P2298320000550000 
P22230Y000003Va0    000000 0000000000 0000000000997  000000000000     Z N2
```

How can I check for a line starting with `P22200I` and then get all subsequent lines under it into a single line until I
find next line starting with `P22200I`? This "roll up" should only be done for lines starting with P22200I.

Output should look like:

```
P220002009034028180002          SSM      200903 
P22200I2004220000    0408832000000000  P222500903200015{
P22200I2008660000    85328187000026574 P224678090033336{ P22230Y000003Va0  000000
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you specify what you already tried? Otherwise, contributors might suggest solutions you already know won't work.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS="" }
  FNR>1 && /^P22200I/{ printf "\n" }
  1
  END{ printf "\n" }
' file
```

Set the output record separator to an empty string (default `\n`) and print a newline if the current line is not the first line and the line starts with `P22200I`. Then print the current line (`1`).
Print another newline when the end of the file is reached.

Output:

```
P220002009034028180002          SSM      200903
P22200I2004220000     0408832000000000 P222500903200000015{ P22261000005500000 
P22200I2008660000    8532818700000000 P22467809000033336{ P2298320000550000 P22230Y000003Va0    000000 0000000000 0000000000997  000000000000     Z N2
```